# Send a tweet from iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, twitter

I want to add a simple limited Twitter function to my app: a user of the app enters his Twitter username and password and tweet text, and presses a button and the tweet is sent.  My app can process notification of success or failure (for example, if the password or username was invalid).

I promise I've watched a hundred YouTube videos and scoured the 'Net. Has anyone seen a simple tutorial or presentation to allow me to do this?

Comment: have you looked at the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Twitter Developer site](http://dev.twitter.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is one-way posting to Twitter, you might be better off using [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/), which is a little simpler than the alternatives people have mentioned so far and also supports other services, such as Facebook.

Comment: I've never heard of them before, pretty handy, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this engine that integrates the Twitter API with Objective C:

[MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

And a good tutorial here:

[Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/)

I used this engine, and its overall very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

For those in 2015 looking for an answer for iOS it is the social framework

```
#import <Social/Social.h>

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
            {
              UIImage *img = someImage;

            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                                   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText: @"my tweet text change it to your needs"];
            [tweetSheet addImage:img];
            [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com"]];
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [bengottlieb / Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) for a complete implementation of the API.

You have to implement O-Auth and can't simply manage your users' password and login yourself anymore. 
Twitter-Oauth-iPhone includes MGTwitterEngine by Matt Gemmell, OAuthConsumer Framework by Jon Crosby, OAuth-MyTwitter by Chris Kimpton, etc. in a relatively simple programming interface.